# Import existing Android NDK project into VS2015 RC and RTM

Tags: android, android-ndk, visual-studio-2015

I am working on a Android NDK project(it's cocos-2dx project)
and I want import this project into Visual Studio 2015.

I googled, but couldn't find any information about how to do this.

How can I import existing Android NDK project into VS2015?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing if you got the VS2015 Community or Enterprise that was recently released, you could download it with the VS installer. If you already have a VS2015 installed, then go to Program and Features on you computer, go to Uninstall a program, look for Visual Studio 2015, click on it, the installer should come up, then click the modify button at the bottom of the installer, it should walk you through the installation process then you can check what you need to also be installed along with what is already there.